# DataSource remains unaltered after deleting rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

My application features a DataGridView which is attached to a simple List (which I serialize to an XML file).  Changing values and adding rows works fine.  However when I delete rows from the DataViewGrid the following happens:

- The selected rows disappear in the GUI
- The selected rows get removed from the BindingList
- The main List, however, remains unaltered

The following code is responsible for the deletion:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    dataGridView.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: You are only removing the rows from the actual GridViews rows collection not the underlying DataSource. Remove the rows from the DataSource and rebind the Data.

Comment: It does work now.  I added a UserDeletingRow event handler to remove the row from the DataSource.  The DataGridView then takes care of making the row disappear visually.  However I now struggle to repair an external button for deleting a row.  I tried raising a fake row deletion event, but I've found no way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, something like this *should* work for you:

```
List<MyObject> data = dataGridView.DataSource as List<MyObject>;
data.Remove(objectToDelete);
```

Should be enough.